# How to add contents on top of an image in C#

Tags: html, css, position

I am creating a website in C# where I need to add content on top of an image. The image should not be set to a background image, except it should be set within the ***img*** tag. Whenever I try to add content, such as, a table or label to appear on top of the image, it either appears before or after the image, and not on the image itself. How do I make the content appear on the image I have added? Please help.

Here's my code :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="main">
        <div id="bg2">
            <img src="Pics/slide.png" style="width:100%; height:100%">
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </img>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Any other ideas on how I can achieve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DGibbs It works. Sorry about that. I hadn't tested it properly. Thank You.  Post it as the answer so I can tick it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position:relative;` to the containing element e.g. `bg2` and `position:absolute;` to your text.

This will take the content out of the document flow and allow you to position the text, relative to the parent relatively position element, in this case bg2.

For example:

```
#bg2
{ 
    position:relative; 
}

#bg2 input[type="text"] 
{ 
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%; 
    left:50%; 
}
```

[Further reading](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at absolute positioning:
http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/